# How to access a JavaScript object property with addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm displaying images which will dynamically added on click of a html button. Using `addEventListener` I want to add an on click function to these images which will access another property of the object so it can be displayed.

This is what my code look likes:

```
    var fruit = function(type, cost)
        {
            this.type = type;
            this.cost = cost;
            this.image = new Image();
            this.image.src = "fruits/" +type +".png";                   
        }
    var fruitArray = new Array();

    fruitArray[0] = new fruit("apple", 0.35);
    fruitArray[1] = new fruit("mango", 0.55);
    fruitArray[2] = new fruit("orange", 0.15);

    function printFruits()
    {
        var counter = 0;
        var element = document.getElementById("div1");
        for(counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++)
        {
            fruitArray[counter].image.addEventListener("click", function fruitType() {
                window.alert(this.type);
            });
            element.appendChild(fruitArray[counter].image);

        }
    }
```

At the moment I'm displaying `'fruitArray[counter].image.type'` (which is undefined).

I want to know if there is a way you can derefernce the image property in order to display `'fruitArray[counter].type'`, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You could potentially attach your fruit instance onto the image element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), like:

```
function printFruits() {
    var counter = 0,
        element = document.getElementById("div1"),
        item;

    function onClick() {
        window.alert(this.type);
    }

    for (counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) {
        item = fruitArray[counter];

        item.image.addEventListener("click", onClick.bind(item));
        element.appendChild(item.image);

    }
}
```

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the type in an immediate function inside the `for` loop:

```
for(counter = 0; counter < 2; counter++) {
    (function() {
        var thisType = fruitArray[counter].type
        fruitArray[counter].image.addEventListener("click", function fruitType() {
          console.log(thisType);
        });
    })();
    element.appendChild(fruitArray[counter].image);
}
```